# MIPS translation from java

Tags: recursion, mips, maze

I'm working on making a recursive maze solver program in MIPS and i'm trying to implement an algorithm that our professor gave us. However, i'm stuck on how i would implement

```
boolean p = solveMaze(r - 1, c, r, c);
```

when i'm creating the program in MIPS. Basically, how i would turn a java boolean expression such as this into MIPS.

Comment: Can you show us what you have came up with so far?

Comment: well this is just part of a much larger program, but essentially what i do is load the arguments and then call solveMaze. Then, the first thing solveMaze does is check if the maze is solved and then if it is, it sets $v0 to 1, for true, and then does jr $ra to get out of the recursive call. But i'm not sure if i'm thinking about it the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In assembly, booleans are usually represented by integers. Also functions return values using registers. Essentially the program will look similar to this

```
...
main:
    # store parameters in registers $a0 to $a3
    jal solveMaze
    mov $t0, $v0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall    # prints 1 or 0 depending on what was returned

solveMaze: # $a0 = r - 1, $a1 = c, $a2 = r, $a3 = c
    ...    # Do what needs to be done here
    li $v0, 1  # $v0 contains 1 which means true, change to 0 for false
    jr $ra     # return to the caller of the function
```